# Java program test using Groovy using maven getting 0 Tests run

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I am trying to test a sample java program with groovy maven.

When i run mvn test

i am getting below output

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.783s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 06 08:47:22 IST 2018
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/54M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can you please check why i am getting 0 tests run.

POM File source link: https://github.com/hemanth22/GroovyLearning/blob/codecoverage/pom.xml

Java and Groovy code source link: https://github.com/hemanth22/GroovyLearning/tree/codecoverage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is OK there.

To run individual test case by passing a test case name as mvn property use:

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=AddTests
```

To run all test cases use:

```
mvn clean package
```

Comment: Still it is same.

But below command worked for me.

mvn clean test -Dtest=AddTests

Comment: Instead of adding manually class name in the mvn clean test, is it possible to detect groovy test case class automatically do testing with java program.

Comment: Yes, sure, just use mvn clean package.

Comment: i have tried using mvn clean package but still it is show 0 tests run. Please find the test result in link : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/cE9gyOahJhamQOLifhsdPQ

Comment: Oh... Surefire can't see a test file. Rename your AddTests.groovy to AddTest.groovy for a start!  @BitraHemanth

Comment: It worked thank you very much @MS90.
Please mark this issue as resolved.

Comment: Glad it helped! You can mark it as resolved by flagging this answer as best answer( belove 0 on left side).  @BitraHemanth